# css selector or xpath selector

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a div in the code. I dont want to display it or delete it. Either is ok

the following is the code:

```
  <div addthis:url="http://sampletest.com/?p=2748" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:title="Clarifying the event "></div>
```

this is from wordpress page.

I dont know in css how to select addthis:url="http://sampletest.com/?p=2748" and addthis:title="Clarifying the event " because class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style is not unique thing to slect

I tried using javascript

```
    element = document.evaluate('//div[@addthis:url="http://sampletest.com/?p=2748"]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
```

but it selects none.

Comment: Can you add a `class` or `id` to it that would allow you to distinguish it?

Comment: i think this code i generated by worpress. i dont have control. i can only change the css or do some javascript thing after page is loaded

Comment: and you want to hide this? just add `display: none` to the CSS

Comment: but what will be my css selector. i dont want to hide any other

Comment: is there any way you can specify it based on one of its containers?

Answer (score 0):

It has a class.  All you have to do is target that class in your CSS.

The class is `addthis_toolbox`, so the following will hide the `div` and its contents.

```
.addthis_toolbox {
    display: none;
}
```

Just make sure this class isn't used in other elements that you don't wish to hide, otherwise they'll be hidden as well.